# ¿Como puedo extraer solamente los números de una variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando sacar solamente los números de una variable en donde contiene un texto.

```
texto = "Pepe guapo 123" #De aquí solo quiero extraer el 123.
print(texto)
```

Se que se podría hacer de esta manera:

```
texto = "Pepe guapo 123"
print(texto[10:14])
```

No es la forma que busco porque en esta variable pueden tener diferente longitud, etc.
¿Se podrá usar algo así?:

```
#Pseudocódigo:
texto = "Pepe tiene 20 años, y le gusta la computación. Se la pasa 24 horas en la computadora. En cambio su hermano mayor Jose (Tiene 25 años) es mas aficionado al deporte y juega si o si al fútbol 2 veces por semana."

for solo_numeros in texto:
 print(texto.int) #extraería solamente los números de la variable del texto.

 #el resultado: 20 24 25 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para dar otra alternativa a la de @manduinca

Una buena forma de tratar texto en python es con el módulo, `re` y usando **expresiones regulares.** En este ejemplo le indicamos que busque todos los dígitos en el string y los extraiga en una lista.

```
import re
texto = "Pepe tiene 20 años, y le gusta la computación. Se la pasa 24 horas en la computadora. En cambio su hermano mayor Jose (Tiene 25 años) es mas aficionado al deporte y juega si o si al fútbol 2 veces por semana."

#Primero ponemos la expresión regular, y luego la variable a la que le queremos aplicar
#dicha expresión
re.findall('\d+', texto)
```

Comment: Muestra como usar findall en un for para imprimir todos los numeros. Asi quedara completo el ejemplo.

Answer (score 4):

```
for c in texto:
    if c.isnumeric():
        print(c)
```